# laravel keep guest's session after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have a public form but it can only be sent after successful login. Therefor I save the data in session. Unfortunately, the data is gone after login. How can I save the session data beyond login?

Thanks in advance!

Andreas

Comment: please provide some code that you do.

Comment: you can just keep data in DB

Comment: And how? When the data of the guest is stored how do I know which data I have to pull? There can be multiple guests at the same time.

Comment: Use a cookie to set a unique ID for the user when they visit the page. Store the data wherever you want using the unique ID as the identifier, after login get the value from the cookie and retrieve the correct data from your storage method.